# Error in insert query of sqlite

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am making an iphone app, in which I am using sqlite. In one class when I tried to insert a string it get crash and giving the following error

`-[CFString UTF8String]:` message sent to deallocated instance 0xe555220

I don't know Why it is happening.

Following is the insert query which I am implementing.

```
-(void)againinsert
{
sqlite3_stmt *addStmt = nil;

if(addStmt == nil) 
{ 
    NSString *str = @"don't know";
    const char *sql = "insert into medicationdetail1(doctorname, emailid, medicationname,   status) values (?,?,?,?)";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql , -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [comparedoctorname UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [globalemail    UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 4, [comparemedic UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 7, [str UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

}

}
```

When the breakpoint moves from second to third statement it get crash.

Please provide the solution.

Thanku very much.

Comment: why u wright 4 and 7 in third fourth line

Comment: it should kill because of you are inserting 4 columns date you use 4 and 7 replace with 3 and 4 it will work fine

Comment: I have found the error, Actually the string which I am trying to insert they all are null. dats why it is giving error. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this one

```
sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [comparemedic UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 4, [str UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

USE

```
sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [comparedoctorname UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [globalemail    UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [comparemedic UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 4, [str UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```